# Upload table to bigquery using Colab, specifying schema in job_config

Tags: python, datatable, google-bigquery, google-colaboratory

I am trying to write a table to bigquery using Colab. The best way to do it I find is using client and job_config. It is important that I maintain control over how data is written as I plan to use below code for different tasks. The last step that eludes me is setting up schema. I do not want someone's query to crash as say Year is suddenly integer instead of a string. The below code should work? Or perhaps I need to use "job_config.schema_update_options", but I am not sure how schema object should look ? I cannot use pandas gbq as it is too slow to write to dataframe first. Table would be overwritten each month, that is why write_truncate. Thanks

```
schema_1 = [
 { "name": "Region",    "type": "STRING",   "mode": "NULLABLE" },
 { "name": "Product",   "type": "STRING",   "mode": "NULLABLE" } ]

schemma2 = [('Region', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, ()),
 ('Product', 'STRING', 'NULLABLE', None, ())]

"""Create a Google BigQuery input table.
In the code below, the following actions are taken:
* A new dataset is created "natality_regression."
* A query is run, the output of which is stored in a new "regression_input" table.
"""

from google.cloud import bigquery

# Create a new Google BigQuery client using Google Cloud Platform project defaults.
project_id = 'nproject'
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

# Prepare a reference to a new dataset for storing the query results.
dataset_id = "natality_regression"
table_id = "regression_input"
table_id_full = f"{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}"

# Configure the query job.
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

# Set the destination table to where you want to store query results.
job_config.destination = table_id_full
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE' # WRITE_APPEND
job_config.schema = schemma2
#job_config.schema_update_options = ???
#job_config.schema = schema_1

# Set up a query in Standard SQL
query = """
    SELECT * FROM `nproject.SalesData1.Sales1` LIMIT 15
"""

# Run the query.
query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
query_job.result()  # Waits for the query to finish
print('danski')
```

Answer (score 0):

This needs to be doing effectively by the job_config but the syntaxis for python is like this:

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("mode", "STRING"),
    ]
)
```

You can find more details here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas?hl=es_419

You can create the table first too, as you mentioned in the query:

```
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("full_name", "STRING", mode="REQUIRED"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("age", "INTEGER", mode="REQUIRED"),
]

table = bigquery.Table(table_id, schema=schema)
table = client.create_table(table)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Created table {}.{}.{}".format(table.project, table.dataset_id, table.table_id)
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but I get bunch of errors, " configuration["query"]["query"] = self.query". Would you be able to write the whole code? LoadJob seems to require client.load... from file or Uri, but I am running an sql  query

Comment: Oh, I didn't check that sorry, yes, you can create the table first to use it in queries. I left an example editing the answer.

Comment: Hi, interesting :).  If I use Write_Truncate schema will be overwritten based on the data type in the query result. Then the best that I can do is delete the data from the table (using Truncate Table table_id_full) and use write_append.

Comment: yup seems to be that the way to do it in different steps